# FinancialDerivative with a delayed start

Tags: functions, core-language, finance, calculus-and-analysis

Using the function FinancialDerivative with an Asian style option doesn't seem to have a parameter that allows for a contract that averages over a specific time period in the future rather than over the entire contract life (e.g. if I enter into a contract today (2/6/17) that averages over the daily values of the underlying from 1/1/18 - 12/31/18). The argument "Inception"-> requires a negative value.

How can I use FinancialDerivative to calculate the value of these instruments?

Comment: interesting question... Is it possible to include parts of code, so we can see exactly what you're doing? BTW, have you contacted Wolfram people to ask about your question? Thanks in advance!